# Https on iis not working with domain name of ip address

Tags: windows, networking, iis, https

Using Windows 2012 R2 Standard server with IIS. Windows firewall has preset rules World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In) and World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In) enabled. The server has one web with the following bindings:

http - *empty value / any domain* - 80
http - example.com - 80
https - example.com - 443
https - *empty value / any domain* - 443

Urls tried from external machine:
http://example.com - works
http://my.ip.address - works
https://example.com - not working
https://my.ip.address - not working

Urls tried from local server
http://example.com - works
http://localhost - works
http://my.ip.address - works
https://example.com - not working
https://localhost - works
https://my.ip.address - not working

So http works for all addresses from all locations. Https works when run on local machine with address localhost but https does not work in any other way. What am I missing? Do I need to open other firewall rules/ports other than 443?

Comment: what is the common name of your SSL certificate ?
it clearly looks like an SSL certificate error

Comment: also, are you using a self-signed certificate or a certificate signed by a CA ?

Comment: regarding the firewall, you can try a simple "telnet <server> 443" from the remote server and see if the port 443 is opened

Comment: Sorry everyone, I had only forwarded port 80 and not 443 in my router. Now everything is working.

Comment: please answer or close question

Answer (score 0):

the usual firewall / NAT issue

> Sorry everyone, I had only forwarded port 80 and not 443 in my router.
>   Now everything is working.